# Keep things in the same domain - PHP session variable loss

Tags: php, session

I'm trying to have a $_SESSION variable within a session. I did

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
```

right on the top of a file called "login.php".

I then set

`if(isset($_POST["id"]))
    $_SESSION['ID'] = $_POST['id'];`

(Update) When I redirect to another page using this:

```
if($psword === $password){
    //echo $_SESSION['ID'];
    header("Location: memberMain.php");
    die();
    exit();
} else {
    echo "Wrong Password.";
    // remove all session variables
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
}
```

, the $_SESSION variable is lost. It gives me `Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\xampp\htdocs\memberMain.php on line 18` I assume it's because the domain is changed.

memberMain.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Member Home</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Member Home</h1>
<a href="reservation.php">Make Reservation</a>
<br>
<a href="reviewMembership.php">Review Membership</a>
<br>
<a href="logoff.php">Log Off</a>
<br>
<a href="resetPassword.php">Reset Password</a>

<?php
 echo $_SESSION['ID'];
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm using XAMPP and all the files run on localhost and are all stored in folder called "htdocs". It doesn't make sense why the variable is lost.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: add die; after header("Location: memberMain.php");

Comment: You require `session_start()` on **every** page you intend to call `$_SESSION`. Which means you'll need it on your `memberMain.php` page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start the session on **every** page you want to access `$_SESSION` through.

```
<?php 
session_start();
```

Is generally the first 2 lines of every php file that uses sessions. It is safe and is required if you want to be able to use `$_SESSION` variables anywhere on those pages.

It has nothing to do with the domains changing (the pages). Your issue is what I've stated above.

Answer (score 1):

try changing your code like below,

```
header("Location: memberMain.php");
exit();
```

Comment: I tried this and please check the update. I tried to put `<?php
session_start(); ?>` in the beginning of every file and it seems to carry the variables, but not sure if it's a safe thing to do..

Comment: @user3763711 No worries.. Its correct to have session_start() on each page, But to simplify and standardize you can have a config file and put all necessary things together and include config.php in all pages